# Xamarin test recorder Instruments failed to start the app

Tags: testing, xamarin, recorder

can any one help me out i'm selected iphone5s simulator and selected after loading its giving error Instruments failed to start the app.

Answer (score 1):

I too am having this same issue.

Im running a xamarin uitest application with and iphone 5 as my phyiscial device.

Ive enabled UI Testing on the device.
Ive specifiend the app bundle.

If I spewcify the device identifier I get the error that it is not a simulator and incompatible with app bundle.

My tests work fine on android devices. If I specify an apple simulator, it will run.

Thanks for your thoughts